# Angular - Problem running forRoot function

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a strange TS problem which I only just started getting after upgrading from Angular 5.x to 7.x.

For this code below, specifically the `forRoot` call for `LibCoreModule`, I get this error:

> ERROR Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'any[]
>   | Type'.   Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to
>   type 'Type'.
>       Property 'apply' is missing in type 'ModuleWithProviders'.

Code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ]
})

export class LibCoreModule {

  public static forRoot(configFactory, deps = []): ModuleWithProviders {

    return {
      ngModule: LibCoreModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: CoreConfig, useFactory: configFactory, deps: deps}
      ]
    };
  }
}

export function coreFactory(): CoreConfig {

  return {
    api: environment.api
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    // SHOWS ERROR
    LibCoreModule.forRoot(coreFactory, [])
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I've tried to see if they changed anything from v5 to v7 but I haven't found anything in particular.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried removing `node_modules` and `packages-lock` and fresh install of `node_modules` using `npm install`?

Comment: @TalhaJunaid Tried that now, same issue unfortunately.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz you should move `LibCoreModule.forRoot(coreFactory, [])` from `declaration` to `import` property, i think this could be solve your problem, because module must be inject in `import` property.

Comment: @Sanoj_V Can't believe I didn't see that... I usually have imports as the first array so got tricked -.- Thanks! I'll accept it if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok i will post an answer!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `LibCoreModule.forRoot(coreFactory, [])` from `declarations` to `imports` property, i think this could be solve your problem, **because module should be inject into imports property**